# Make an insert with the values returned by another query directly (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Im doing a PHP script for insert in the table A values recovered from the table B (A and B are in different databases).

```
 Table A Columns
 [index(autoincrement),timestamp(currenttimestamp),col1,col2,.....col15]
```

and I have the query for retrieve the values from B:

```
$query= "select count(*) as col1, XXX as col2.....ZZZ as col15 from B";
```

so having  the

```
$row=$mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

where

```
$result=mysql_query($query)
```

how can I make an

```
insert into A (col1,col2.....col15) values ($row['col1'],....$row['col15'];
```

easily without write all the code? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Insert into db1.A (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM db2.B
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell that both tables are in different databases

Comment: Same server/user? If so I've updated my answer. Else you'll have to right the PHP code I think

Answer (score 2):

If you have to transfer the data across databases on different servers, you can use sprintf and implode to generate your query.

```
$query = sprintf('INSERT INTO table_name (%s) VALUES ("%s")', implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($row))), implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $row)));
```